# Every time I click on shop name its throwing an error instead of printing location

Tags: php, mysql

On the left side I have sidebar menu in which I have 16 shops name which are fed from a database and on right side I want to print location (string) that is also retrieved from the database. But when I click on specific shop, I get this error:

> unknown column '[shop name]'` in where clause

Please help. Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die(mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db('shop',$con) or die(mysql_error());

$sql='Select name,location from info';
$retrieval=mysql_query($sql,$con);
if(!$retrieval) {
    die('Could not get data'.mysql_error());
}
$name=$_GET['name'];
 echo "<div class='vertical-menu' >";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($retrieval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    echo "<a href='index.php?name=" . $row['name'] . "'>{$row['name']}</a>";
}
echo "</div>";



$sql1="Select location from info WHERE name=$name" ;
$retrieval1=mysql_query($sql1,$con);
if(!$retrieval1) {
    die('Could not get data'.mysql_error());
}

 echo "<div class='info' >";
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($retrieval1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "{$row1['location']}";
}
echo "</div>";
 ?>

</body></html>
```

Comment: unknown column '[shop name]' in where clause

Comment: Stop using the obsolete `mysql` extension, switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`. Then you can use prepared statements and you won't run into problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHANGE SQL1 QUERY

**FROM THIS**

```
$sql1="Select location from info WHERE name = $name" ;
```

**TO THIS**

```
$sql1="Select location from info WHERE name = '$name' " ;
```

Comment: well this is code for sidebar which is working fine.problem starts where sql1 query is located.that is the code for displaying right side location

Comment: See Updated Answer .!

Answer (score 0):

1. When you working with SQL Queries we need to follow some standards , instead of passing the where parameters we need to pass using prepare call.
   direct call like this [$sql1="Select location from info WHERE name = '$name'] will end up with SQL Injection issue. but for beginners its okay to follow the old tradition way.
2. Also in your query [shop name] this filed not selected in query. may be that filed available in the table, in that case so you can use [select *] in the query.
3. Use the following example to retrieve the data from db.

   ```
   <?php
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "world");


   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
       exit();
   }

   $name=$_GET['name'];
   if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Select name,location from info where name=?")) {
       $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->bind_result($results);
       $stmt->fetch();
       printf("%s is in district %s\n", $results, $name);
       $stmt->close();
   }
   $mysqli->close();
   ?>
   ```